# Two point function for massless boson in 2 dimension

Tags: quantum-field-theory, correlation-functions, greens-functions

Is it true that two point function for massless boson theory in 2 dimension is a constant? That is to say it is independent of the distance between the two points?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's a log:

$$G(x,y) = -\kappa \ln |x-y| + cst.$$
where $\kappa$ depends on how you normalize the fields and the additive constant should actually live inside of the log for dimensional reasons. It should be fixed by imposing asymptotics at 0 or infinity.

The calculation is just a matter of solving Laplace's equation in 2d. It is textbook material and is surely done in the chapter about the free boson in the Di Francesco-Mathieu-Sénéchal textbook.

Comment: Thanks Vibert. I recover your result using the Fourier transform of the momentum space propagator. In fact, the constant added is infinite if the boundary of the system is infinitely large. After a regularization with regard to the boundary size, I can reach a result for the difference of two correlators, which is indeed the same as yours.